# Using @OneToOne mapping but Foreign key does not fail the constraint or not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I am having this ER [image: Er Diagram]

**This is CustomeOrderEntity -:**

```
class CustomerOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    var orderID: Long = 0

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    lateinit var customer: Customer

    @Column(name = "customer_payment_method_id")
    lateinit var customerPaymentMethodId: String

    @Column(name = "order_status_code")
    lateinit var orderStatusCode: String

    @Column(name = "date_order_placed")
    lateinit var dateOrderPlaced: String

    @Column(name = "date_order_paid")
    lateinit var dateOrderPaid: String

    @Column(name = "der_order_price")
    lateinit var derOrderPrice: String

    @Column(name = "other_order_details")
    lateinit var otherOrderDetails: String
}
```

**This is Customer Entity**

```
   data class Customer
(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name ="customer_id" )
    val customerID:Long = 0,

    @Column(name = "customer_name",nullable = false)
    val customerName:String,

    @Column(name = "customer_email",nullable = false)
    val customerEmail:String,

    @Column(name = "customer_phone")
    val customerPhone:String,

    @Column(name = "customer_other_details",nullable = true)
    val customerOtherDetails:String
)
```

When adding customer_order without customers the data added and customer_id field is null.

What I want to do that when adding customer_order it first checks customer_id exist for customer_order if not then data will not add.

Comment: So, do it... (and remove these insertable = false and updateable = false attributes, since you **want** to insert something in this column). What's the concrete problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Ya, I tried but this does not help.

Comment: You tried what? Post the code that you tried. Tell us precisely what you expect that code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: insertable = false and updateable = false because I don't want that address to add data in the customer table

Comment: insertable false means that even if you set the customer in CustomerOrder, it won't insert anything in the customer_order.customer_id column. Again, remove these two attributes. Then post the code that you tried. Tell us precisely what you expect that code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: What I want to do that when adding customer_order it first checks customer_id exist in customer table if not then it through foreign key exception or other error if customer_id finds in customer table then add data

Comment: So, do it. That's what will happen when persisting a CustomerOrder, if your remove these attributes, and if you have defined a forign key constraint in your database table. Again: remove these two attributes. Then post the code that you tried. Tell us precisely what you expect that code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Updated the Code. It added CustomerOrder without checking if customer_id exist or not what i dont want to do

Comment: Do you have a forign key constraint defined in your database table? That's what guarantees that the order's customer_id can only reference an existing customer ID. If you don't have such a database constraint, then Hibernate can't do anything for you.

Comment: Yes, I have to hibernate created automatically.

Comment: I think the mapping I did is wrong.

Comment: It is wrong now. It was correct (except for the two attributes I told you to remove). It's a ManyToOne, not a OneToOne.

Comment: does not work..